# Login using hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Hi i'm trying to create a login form and use hibernate framework.

```
        String user = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    EntityManagerFactory entityFactory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityFactory.createEntityManager();

    String select = "SELECT userName, passWord FROM UserAccounts WHERE userName='"
            + user + "' and passWord='" + password + "'";

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(select);

    if(query.getResultList().size() == 0){
        System.out.println("Account does not exist!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Login Success!");
        UserAccounts login = (UserAccounts) query; //error here
        System.out.println(login.getUserName());
    }
```

The problem is i'm getting an error when trying to cast the query result to the accounts object.

What is the correct way of converting?
Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that concatenating a JPQL string with request parameters introduces a security leak. One can modify the JPQL with the request parameters.

Comment: And _never_ store plain passwords in a database - use a [secure hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) instead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use variables and bind the parameters to prevent injection attacks and select the `UserAccounts` object.

```
String select = "SELECT ua FROM UserAccounts ua WHERE ua.userName=:userName and ua.passWord=:password";

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(select);
query.setParameter("userName", user);
query.setParameter("password", password);
```

Use `getSingleResult()`, because a user/password should only identify one user. (Also prevents some attacks) and cast it to the class you selected (a `UserAccounts`)

```
UserAccounts ua = (UserAccounts) query.getSingleResult();
```

PS: Never store passwords in plain-text in the database. Use a one-way hash instead. E.g. [`bcrypt`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html)

Comment: Thank you so much!! worked like a charm. and also thank you for the information about the security leak!

Comment: Don't forget to catch `NoResultException` - as `getSingleResult()` expects _exactly_ one result. If the user entered wrong information, you will have no result at all. And @Rene please add a remark that storing plain passwords is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) query. It returns instance of the class `UserAccounts`.

```
String selectQuery = "FROM UserAccounts WHERE userName= :user and passWord= :password";

selectQuery.setParameter("user", user);
selectQuery.setParameter("password", password);
```

Use [Query#setParameter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to set pass parameters to query.